# Error because of quote char after converting file to string with Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, unicode, file-io, delphi-xe

I have incorrect result when converting file to string in Delphi XE. There are several `'` characters that makes the result incorrect. I've used `UnicodeFileToWideString` and `FileToString` from http://www.delphidabbler.com/codesnip and my code :

```
 function LoadFile(const FileName: TFileName): ansistring;
  begin
    with TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite) do
    begin
      try
        SetLength(Result, Size);
        Read(Pointer(Result)^, Size);
        // ReadBuffer(Result[1], Size);
      except
        Result := ''; 
        Free;
      end;
      Free;
    end;
  end;
```

The result between Delphi XE and Delphi 6 is different. The result from D6 is correct. I've compared with result of a hex editor program.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all but I do know that you must not free an object twice like you are doing.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I should use `try..finally`

Comment: I don't understand the question, either. Can you please give an example of the input file, the expected output, and the actual output? Where do you see apostrophes?

Comment: could you also show us the code that calls this function

Comment: @Rob, here's the preview http://imageshack.us/m/84/2955/unledgp.png. First image has invalid result.

Comment: @David, code to call last function : `sBuffer: ansistring; sBuffer := LoadFile(FileName);`

Comment: The preview of what? What does the final result look like? And there's only one image; was there supposed to be a second image to complement the "first image" with the invalid result? Also, the right edge appears to be clipped. Please include a *full* view of the correct and incorrect output.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that AnsiString was never really ideal for storing the contents of a binary file, but as of Delphi 2009, it's a poor choice because of the code-page conversions that Delphi does when assigning strings variables. If you want to hold the contents of a file, use an array of bytes, like `TBytes`, or just load it into a `TMemoryStream`.

Comment: Here's the correct result with D6 : http://i51.tinypic.com/fk4kyo.jpg and the incorrect result with DXE : http://i51.tinypic.com/2lc8pbn.jpg . Rob, the reason I use AnsiString or String because I want to convert the binary to a hex string format. Okay, I think I will try to convert bytes to hex string.

Comment: Can you please tell us what function you used to produce the output you've shown? The `LoadFile` function you have here does not produce strings of the format you've shown in your pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is being produced in the style of the Delphi debugger, which displays string variables using Delphi's own string-literal format. Whatever function you're using to produce that output from your own program has actually been *fixed* for Delphi XE. It's really your Delphi 6 output that's incorrect.

Delphi string literals consist of a series of *printable* characters between apostrophes and a series of *non-printable* characters designated by number signs and the numeric values of each character. To represent an apostrophe, write two of them next to each other. The printable and non-printable series of characters can be written right not to each other; there's no need to concatenate them with the `+` operator.

Here's an excerpt from the output you say is correct:

> `#$12'O)=ù'dlû'#6't`

There are four lone apostrophes in that string, so each one either opens or closes a series of printable characters. We don't necessarily know which is which when we start reading the string at the left because the `#`, `$`, `1`, and `2` characters are all printable on their own. But if they represent printable characters, then the `0`, `)`, `=`, and `ù` characters are in the non-printable region, and that can't be. Therefore, the first apostrophe above *opens* a printable series, and the `#$12` part represents the character at code 18 (12 in hexadecimal). After the `ù` is another apostrophe. Since the previous one *opened* a printable string, this one must *close* it. But the next character after that is `d`, which is not `#`, and therefore cannot be the start of a non-printable character code. Therefore, this string from your Delphi 6 code is mal-formed.

The correct version of that excerpt is this:

> `#$12'O)=ù''dlû'#6't`

Now there are *three* lone apostrophes and one set of *doubled* apostrophes. The problematic apostrophe from the previous string has been doubled, indicating that it is a literal apostrophe instead of a printable-string-closing one. The printable series continues with `dlû`. Then it's closed to insert character No. 6, and then opened again for `t`. The apostrophe that opens the entire string, at the beginning of the file, is *implicit*.

You haven't indicated what code you're using to produce the output you've shown, but *that's* where the problem was. It's not there anymore, and the code that *loads* the file is correct, so the only place that needs your debugging attention is any code that depended on the old, incorrect format. You'd still do well to replace your code with [that of Robmil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013359/error-because-of-quote-char-after-converting-file-to-string-with-delphi-xe/6013858#6013858) since it does better at handling (or not handling) exceptions and empty files.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is great. Somehow there's unintended problem with my input file so I was confused about the result. Anyway, I have done what I want to do (convert : binary file => ansistring => hex string, match the hex string with my Delphi 6 pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, looking at the real data, your problem is that the file stores binary data, not string data, so interpreting this as a string is not valid at all. The only reason it works at all in Delphi 6 is that non-Unicode Delphi allows you to treat binary data and strings the same way. You cannot do this in Unicode Delphi, nor should you.

The solution to get the actual text from within the file is to read the file as binary data, and then copy any values from this binary data, one byte at a time, to a string if it is a "valid" Ansi character (printable).

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest the code:

```
function LoadFile(const FileName: TFileName): AnsiString;
begin
  with TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite) do
  try
    SetLength(Result, Size);
    if Size > 0 then
      Read(Result[1], Size);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why? Although this is undeniably better code than the original, can you please explain why you think this code will actually solve the problem? (Maybe you could explain the problem, too, because I don't understand what it is.)

Comment: Why ? Because it works properly regarding exception handling. The problem probably is in reading a non-ANSI text file. So, the Result has a non readable string ?

Comment: Just for clarify that the code doesn't produce same code with my code because your code can't read non-ANSI and there are still apostrophes in result.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly for handling exceptions. But what reason do you have to think that exceptions are the problem here? Non-Ansi text files don't cause exceptions.

Comment: How do you verify string ? Evaluate / Modify ? Then it will double apostrophes in the text, according to Delphi syntax.

Comment: Compare with the correct result. The correct result is `#0#0#0#$10#0#0#0'0'#1#0'é†'#4#0#0'@'#1#0#0` and your result is `#0#0#0#$10#0#0#0'0'#1#0#0'’'#1#0#0'@'#1#0#0`.